# How does R treat nonexistent index values?

Tags: r, subset

Consider this experiment:

```
Rgames> oof<-c(6,7,8,0,10)
Rgames> badoof<-vector()
Rgames> oof[badoof]
numeric(0)
Rgames> oof[-badoof]
numeric(0)
Rgames> oof[-0]
numeric(0)
Rgames> oof[-10]
[1]  6  7  8  0 10
Rgames> oof[-c(10,0)]
[1]  6  7  8  0 10

Rgames> oof[!(1:length(oof)%in% c(badoof) )]
[1]  6  7  8  0 10
```

I know that "only negative integers can be mixed with zeroes" is a limit on subsetting.  The part that isn't clear to me is why both `oof[badoof]` and `oof[-badoof]` return nothing.   The background here is that I've got a function which searches for bad data and removes them from a vector of data. I was hoping not to have to treat the case where no bad items were found (i.e. `badoof` has no elements) separately or via an if/else.  The very last example above, the one using `%in%` works, but I wonder why `R` doesn't accept the index "-badoof" construction.

Edit: in light of Hong Ooi's answer, I should ask as well: isn't it the case that the use of a negative sign inside `[]` really is a "NOT" operation, rather than changing the actual value of the designated indices?

Comment: A more efficient alternative to your work around might be `oof[if (length(badoof) > 0) -badoff else TRUE]`

Comment: @agstudy yep, sorry -- fixed in edit.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde  That would work, but for OCD reasons :-) I'm trying not to have an if/else.

Comment: Both `oof[badoof]` and `oof[-badoof]` return nothing because the underlying C code is looping over the index vector.  If the index vector is length zero, the loop doesn't execute and a zero-length vector is returned. Regarding your edit, that's not the case. The `-` is not parsed any different inside `[` than it is at the top level, which is to say it _does_ act on the value of the indices before passing them to `[`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks for the info.  So now I know :-) .  I'll have to invent some horrible code which passes `indexvalues<-c(-4,-3,-2)` to `foo[-indexvalues]` just for obfuscatory purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because of this:

```
> x <- numeric(0)
> x
numeric(0)
> -x
numeric(0)
> identical(x, -x)
[1] TRUE
```

IOW, negating a vector with no elements leaves the vector unchanged, and hence the indexing operation using the vector will also be unchanged.

Comment: That part I get -- it just seems a bit inconsistent with the fact that  `R` has no problem ignoring the "10" in oof[-10] when that's an index value out of range.  `0` is also a value out of range, but it gets treated differently (as does `numeric(0)` which admittedly is not a value)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: I agree it's weird, but not necessarily inconsistent. `10` may be out of range, but it's a _possible_ value. Index values of `0` or `integer(0)` will _never_ be in _any_ vector. So I think the difference is between an index value that could exist, but doesn't, versus index values that can never exist.